# How to uninstall Cloud Foundry CLI on Mac OSX?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have installed Cloudfoundry version 6.10 using installer [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli).

It looks like using **brew**  would be better solution to keep up with new releases.  I would like to uninstall current version of CF CLI so i could let brew manage my CF cli upgrades.

Do we have uninstall instructions documented somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CF CLI is a compiled binary, removing the file itself should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

The OS X installer creates a binary, `/usr/local/bin/cf` and a directory, `/usr/local/share/doc/cf-cli`.

Deleting those would fully uninstall it.